# Creating a "table of tables" in PostgreSQL or achieving similar functionality?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm just getting started with PostgreSQL, and I'm new to database design.

I'm writing software in which I have various plugins that update a database.  Each plugin periodically updates its own designated table in the database.  So a plugin named 'KeyboardPlugin' will update the 'KeyboardTable', and 'MousePlugin' will update the 'MouseTable'.  I'd like for my database to store these 'plugin-table' relationships while enforcing referential integrity.  So ideally, I'd like a configuration table with the following columns:

1. Plugin-Name (type 'text')
2. Table-Name (type ?)

My software will read from this configuration table to help the plugins determine which table to update.  Originally, my idea was to have the second column (Table-Name) be of type 'text'.  But then, if someone mistypes the table name, or an existing relationship becomes invalid because of someone deleting a table, we have problems.  I'd like for the 'Table-Name' column to act as a reference to another table, while enforcing referential integrity.

What is the best way to do this in PostgreSQL?  Feel free to suggest an entirely new way to setup my database, different from what I'm currently exploring.  Also, if it helps you answer my question, I'm using the pgAdmin tool to setup my database.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please, do not use a table for each individual plugin.  Standardize the functionality, and use as few tables as possible.  [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) is a common solution for flexibility

Comment: Interesting!  This could be handy.  Before I delve deeper, I'm wondering if under this model there would be a way to have attribute TYPES.  From my brief look into the article, what I understand for my problem is that I would make an Attribute table, with the first column mentioning what plugin this attribute is for (linked to a plugin table), and the second column for the 'value' of the attribute.  This would mean that every attribute will have the same data type, which I would make 'text', and then cast it.  So no types then?

Comment: Actually I confused myself.  The first column would be the attribute name, and the second would be the plugin it belongs to.  I'll read up more about it and see if I can figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with your original plan to store the name as text. Possibly enhanced by additionally storing the *schema* name:

```
 addin text
,sch   text
,tbl   text
```

Tables have an `OID` in the system catalog (`pg_catalog.pg_class`). You can get those with a [nifty special cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html):

```
SELECT 'myschema.mytable'::regclass
```

But the `OID` can change over a dump / restore. So just store the names as text and verify the table is there by casting it like demonstrated at application time.

Of course, if you use each tables for multiple addins it might pay to make a separate table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
 ,tbl_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 ,sch    text
 ,name   text
 );
```

and reference it in ...

```
CREATE TABLE addin (
 ,addin_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 ,addin    text
 ,tbl_id   integer REFERENCES tbl(tbl_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

Or even make it an n:m relationship if addins have multiple tables.  But be aware, as @OMG_Ponies commented, that a setup like this will require you to execute a lot of dynamic SQL because you don't know the identifiers beforehand.

Comment: Storing table names ensures the use of dynamic SQL.

Comment: This looks pretty neat.  But with this am I not still relying on my software to verify that the table exists?  Isn't there a way to tie the constraint into the database itself so that trying to store a table reference to a table that doesn't exist will automatically fail?  My system will handle many, many plugins and I don't want it to start getting sloppy.

Answer (score 2):

I guess all plugins have a set of basic attributes and then each plugin will have a set of plugin-specific attributes. If this is the case you can use a single table together with the [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) datatype (a standard extension that just needs to be installed).

Something like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE plugins 
 (
    plugin_name              text not null primary key,
    common_int_attribute     integer not null, 
    common_text_attribute    text not null, 
    plugin_atttributes       hstore
 )
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO plugins 
 (plugin_name, common_int_attribute, common_text_attribute, hstore)
 VALUES
 ('plugin_1', 42, 'foobar', 'some_key => "the fish", other_key => 24'), 
 ('plugin_2', 100, 'foobar', 'weird_key => 12345, more_info => "10.2.4"');
```

This creates two plugins named plugin_1 and plugin_2

Plugin_1 has the additional attributes "some_key" and "other_key", while plugin_2 stores the keys "weird_key" and "more_info".

You can index those `hstore` columns and query them very efficiently. 
The following will select all plugins that have a key "weird_key" defined.

```
SELECT *
FROM plugins
WHERE plugin_attributes ? 'weird_key'
```

The following statement will select all plugins that have a key `some_key` with the value `the fish`:

```
SELECT *
FROM plugins
WHERE plugin_attributes @> ('some_key => "the fish"')
```

Much more convenient than using an EAV model in my opinion (and most probably a lot faster as well).

The only drawback is that you lose type-safety with this approach (but usually you'd lose that with the EAV concept as well).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an application catalog. Just add the application name to the keys of the table. This of course assumes that all the tables have the same structure. If not: use the application name for a table name, or as others have suggested: as a schema name( which also would allow for multiple tables per application).

EDIT:
But the real issue is of course that you should *first* model your data, and *than* build the applications to manipulate it. **The data should not serve the code; the code should serve the data.**